# How keep intellij idea index between restarts?

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

When I close Intellij Idea and start it again it begin indexing files, but I just close and open (for example after plugin install). Is there a way to "save" this index between restarts and do not refresh it after plugin installs?

Comment: The reindexing happens because of an exception in IntelliJ IDEA. Please locate the exception in your idea.log (Help | Show Log in <file manager>) and post it here.

Comment: It definitely shouldn't restart indexing if the indexing was complete from the previous time, and you didn't do anything to trigger it like for example change the jvm version.

Comment: try right-click on folder you don't want to index, then select **Mark Directory as > Excluded.**

Comment: @yole I have a lot of exceptions in the log (15.0.5). So it looks like there is no way to fix this quickly or to fix it at all?

Comment: @gumkins How could I tell you whether it's possible to fix this if you haven't provided any details about the exceptions? Most likely the exceptions indicate a corrupted index, and saving it would be completely useless.

Comment: Well, if it restarts after you installed a plugin, then AFAIK it really needs to rebuild the index (for example the AngularJS plugin contributes to the index).
If you restart without having installed/uninstalled a plugin, then it should really not start indexing again.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to cancel/disable indexing - it is a core feature, all of IntelliJ functionality (syntax/error highlighting, code completion, code inspections, navigation, refactoring, code coverage, search, etc.) is based on it.
Please try invalidating caches (File/Invalidate caches, Restart) - does the problem persist?

Also, do you have any build tasks running in background? Do they watch your files (i.e. are they triggered on file changing)? I'd suggest excluding all dynamically generated folders from the project (Mark directory as/Excluded) - this should make IntelliJ much faster. Note also that scanning Idea project folders for viruses slows down indexing tremendously, that's why excluding them from from on-access scan is required.

Having said that, you may want to increase the priority of idea.exe and increase cache,heap memory area, etc allocation in vmoptions.